# Разные схемы элемента в зависимости от значения его атрибута

Tags: xml, xsd

Здравствуйте уважаемые! Помогите пожалуйста составить схему для xml-кода:

```
<Подраздел имя="винты">
    <Свойство тип="Число" имя="Диаметр" обозначение="d" единица="мм" />
    <Свойство тип="Число" имя="Шаг" обозначение="p" единица="мм" />
    <Свойство тип="Текст.Варианты" имя="Направление резьбы">
        <Вариант>Правая</Вариант>
        <Вариант>Левая</Вариант>
    </Свойство>
    <Свойство тип="Да/Нет" имя="Полый?"/>Да</Свойство>
</Подраздел>
```

так чтобы:

1. для свойства с тип="Число" наличие дочерних элементов исключалось, а атрибуты обозначение="", единицы="" были обязательными.
2. для свойства тип="Текст.Варианты" требовалось минимум 2 дочерних <вариант>'а, а наличие атрибутов обозначение="", единицы="" запрещалось.
3. для свойства тип="Да/Нет" аналогично пункту 2 + закрывающий тег обязателен, содержимое ограничено двумя вариантами "да" и "нет".

В общих словах требуется составить схему, в которой элемент "Свойство" менял атрибуты и дочерние элементы в зависимости от значения тип="". Да и возможно ли это?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, это невозможно напрямую.

Answer (score 0):

Это невозможно. XSD не поддерживает валидацию по значению. Только по структуре. Замените Ваш XML таким

```xml
<Подраздел имя="винты">
    <Число имя="Диаметр" обозначение="d" единица="мм" />
    <Число имя="Шаг" обозначение="p" единица="мм" />
    <Текст.Варианты имя="Направление резьбы">
        <Вариант>Правая</Вариант>
        <Вариант>Левая</Вариант>
    </Текст.Варианты>
    <Логический имя="Полый?">Да</Логический>
</Подраздел>
```

И задача будет иметь решение

Comment: Видимо так и придётся сделать. Благодарю за помощь!